# How does Linux know what is the mimetype of a file?

Tags: linux, mime-types

How can linux know the mimetype of a file? Is there something written inside the file? Does it look at the extension of the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through the ["magic" bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) in a file. You can do this yourself by running the [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command:

```
file --mime filename
```

To my understanding, the underlying library is [libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic).

Comment: It does use extensions as well... because things like `.txt` don't necessarily have good magic bytes to look for.  The exact implementation may depend on which Desktop Environment you mean (e.g. KDE v.s. GNOME).  However this is an old [freedesktop standard](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec), so the behaviour of most DEs should be very similar.

Comment: How are magic bytes store in a file in practice? In a text file for example?

Comment: @Gradient: There are multiple places. Like `/usr/share/mime/magic`, and `/usr/share/file/magic.mgc` (binary). You can also add your own signatures in `/etc/magic`. At least these are valid files on my Debian system.

Comment: Plain text files are mainly recognized from the _absence_ of certain bytes that stand for unprintable characters.